# Перестала работать форма со скриптом JavaScript, передающим секретное значение для защиты от спама

Tags: php, javascript, html, form, спам

Перестала работать форма обратной связи после попытки сделать защиту от спама. При попытке отправить сообщение, выскакивает станица с надписью "Spam decected".

Суть в том, что при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить заявку" скрипт записывает в пустую переменную секретное значение. От человека переменная приходит с этим значением, а от бота приходит пустая, так-как бот не выполняет js.

В чём может быть проблема?

**Строка в PHP**

```
if ($_POST['check'] != 'secretcode') exit('Spam decected');
```

**Форма**

```html
<form class="s_form" action="contactengine.php" method="post">

<input id="check" name="check" type="hidden" value="" />

<input class="s_text nameinp sinp copy-form" name="Name" placeholder="Имя" type="text">
<input class="s_text nameinp sinp copy-form" name="Email" placeholder="Почта" type="text">
<input class="s_text nameinp sinp copy-form" name="Tel" required placeholder="Телефон" type="text">

<input  class="s_submit copy-form" name="send" value="Отправить заявку" type="submit">
</form>
```

**Скрипт**

```js
function handler(e) {
  var elem = e.target; //e.target  - нажатый элемент, в нашем случае кнопка
  var parent = elem.parentElement; //родительский элемент - при такой разметке будет родительская форма
  var checkInput = parent.getElementsByClassName("check")[0]; //вытягиваем из divа первый нужный инпут
  checkInput.value = "secretcode"; //ставим нужное значение
}
 
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("s_submit copy-form");
for (var i =0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = handler;
}
```

Comment: А если форма отправляется при нажатии на enter?

Comment: Проблема с отправкой при нажатии на enter - пока не столь важна.   Мне главное чтобы она нормально отправлялась при нажатии на кнопку отправить.

Comment: Я чувствую, что проблема где-то на поверхности. Но, догадаться самому - сложно, так-как я не программист. Делаю всё методом тыка по урокам и статьям в сети.

Comment: у Вас велью в хайден инпуте всегда пустой , а пехапе сравинвает пустую сторку с сикрет кодом, и если это не так делает экзит. Все предельно ясно

Comment: Вы ищите по имени класса check, но элемента с таким классом нет. есть элемент с id="check", но это же не класс ...

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы он искал по классу ? ))

Comment: `<input id="check" name="check" type="hidden" value="" />` замените на `<input class="check" name="check" type="hidden" value="" />`

Comment: Блин, действительно )) 
Заменил на класс и теперь всё работает! 
Парни, всех благодарю за содействие!

Comment: @Quantum не забудьте обработать событие нажатия enter в поле видимости формы. Он (enter) будет отправлять форму дефолтом не трогая скрипт.

Comment: Вообще надо вешать обработчик на submit формы

Answer (score 2):

Первый вариант:

Изменить getElementsByClassName("check")[0] на getElementsById("check");

```
var checkInput = parent.getElementsById("check"); //вытягиваем из divа первый нужный инпут
```

Второй вариант

Изменить атрибут в поле ввода id на class

```
<input class="check" name="check" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Третий вариант

Использовать вместо getElementsByClassName, getElementsByName

```
var checkInput = parent.getElementsByName("check")[0]; //вытягиваем из divа первый нужный инпут
```